# How to filter and order by a row that exists on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with 2 columns "id" and "ink_number" and I would like to create another column called "nk_exists" that will have a value of 1 or 0 depending on if there is a row like it but with a "NK" at the beginning. And be able to sort by "nk_exits".

For example if there are two rows "123" and "NK123" then for row "123" nk_exists is true because there exists a row 123 with NK at the beginning.

Here is my original table "inkasso"

```
+-------+--------------+
| id  1 |  ink_number  |
+-------+--------------+
|     1 | 538032S      |
|     2 | NK538032S    |
|     3 | 114702A      |
|     4 | 159631D      |
|     5 | NK9761926001 |
|     6 | 9761926001   |
|     7 | 29-00002411L |
|     8 | 42032502V    |
|     9 | NK42032502V  |
|    10 | 454339KDB    |
+-------+--------------+
```

I want the end result to look like this

```
+-------+--------------+-----------+
| id  1 |  ink_number  | nk_exists |
+-------+--------------+-----------+
|     1 | 538032S      |         1 |
|     2 | NK538032S    |         0 |
|     3 | 114702A      |         0 |
|     4 | 159631D      |         0 |
|     5 | NK9761926001 |         0 |
|     6 | 9761926001   |         1 |
|     7 | 29-00002411L |         0 |
|     8 | 42032502V    |         1 |
|     9 | NK42032502V  |         0 |
|    10 | 454339KDB    |         0 |
+-------+--------------+-----------+
```

My query is getting a synax error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

```
select
    inkasso.id,
    inkasso.ink_number,
    jointable.nk_exists
from inkasso
left join (
    select
        case
            when exists 1
            when not exists 0
        end as nk_exists
    from inkasso
    where exists(
        select
            1
        from inkasso ink
        where left(ink_number, 2) = 'NK' and inkasso.id = ink.id
    ) as subjoin on 
) as jointable on inkasso
WHERE jointable.nk_exists = 1
ORDER BY jointable.nk_exists
```

Comment: Wrong case expression syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
  CONCAT('NK', ink_number) IN (SELECT ink_number FROM inkasso) AS nk_exists
FROM inkasso;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba3d74d28a30ed3a0c26f9378c10062e)

Comment: When I add where nk_exists = 1 then it says unkown column nk_exists

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I followed the question as posed ("I want the end result to look like this"). If you just want to get those rows, either make this a subquery (wasteful) or move the criterion from `FROM` to `WHERE`: `SELECT * FROM inkasso WHERE CONCAT('NK', ink_number) IN (SELECT ink_number FROM inkasso)`.

Comment: here is your fiddle where I added a WHERE clause https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc9fa77350a10efdc77a43b72a1c99a2

Comment: Firstly, I already said you can't do it - `WHERE` clauses can't name columns that are constructed in `SELECT` clause, only columns that are already present in `FROM` clause. Secondly, your syntax is off: a `WHERE` clause can't come before a `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Liga you can't use an alias in a `WHERE` clause, you need to use `HAVING` instead https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e47d8eb5a0ead83958532158702aa81a

Answer (score 1):

If sou want to **add** the column `nk_exists`, you might try something like this:

```
SELECT          ink.id,
                ink.ink_number,
                CASE
                  WHEN nk_ink.id IS NULL THEN 0
                  ELSE                        1
                END AS nk_esists
FROM            inkasso ink
LEFT OUTER JOIN inkasso nk_ink
             ON nk_ink.ink_number = 'NK' + ink.ink_number
```

In case you only want to **filter** on that column, you could try the following:

```
SELECT ink.id,
       ink.ink_number,
FROM   inkasso ink
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT nk_ink.id
               FROM   inkasso nk_ink
               WHERE  nk_ink.ink_number = 'NK' + ink.ink_number)
```